# How to Parse XML from website using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying parse XML from URL, but i got error `FileNotFoundError`

where I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
url = "http://cs.stir.ac.uk/~soh/BD2spring2022/assignmentdata.php"
params = {'data':'spurpyr'}
response = requests.get (url, params)
xml_content = response.content

tree = ET.parse(xml_content)
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ET.parse` parses from a file, instead of `ET.parse` try using `ET.fromstring` and that would probably help. I can't test your specific case since the URL you have written is giving me an error. So, try changing your code to this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
url = "http://cs.stir.ac.uk/~soh/BD2spring2022/assignmentdata.php"
params = {'data':'spurpyr'}
response = requests.get (url, params)
xml_content = response.content

root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)
print(root.tag)
```

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Yeah, I edited it. It should work now.

Comment: How to save children to separate variables, say var_a and var_b, I have run for loop to get them, how do i save them `for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)`

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying but I suppose that you may need a dictionary like this `dict = {}` and in the next line you can do this `for child in root: dict[child.tag] = child.attrib`.

Comment: I want to save them in separate variables

Comment: You can't do that, not without forbidden methods. One of those forbidden methods is to use `exec` and do something like this `exec(f"{child.tag} = child.attrib")` but don't do that because it is not worth it.